# If $\int_0^T g(x) dx =0$, which assumptions are required on $h$ in order to have $\int_0^T h(x) g(x) dx >0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $T>0$ be fixed and let $h$ and $g$ be two continuous non-constant non identically zero functions such that:

1. $\displaystyle\int_0^T g\, dx =0$;

I am trying to understand which assumptions are required on the function $h$ so that
$$\int_0^T h g \ dx >0 \quad\forall x\in [0, T].$$

My unique idea so far is to assume that there exists $M>0$ such that $h(x)\le M$, but I am not convinced about that since $g$ changes its sign.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\int_0^T h(x) g(x) dx$ is a value that does not depend on $x;$ in fact, a general recommendation is to drop garbage symbols and write this more simply as $\int_0^T hg.$ So what you are asking is a bit weird.

Comment: If the integral of $g$ is zero and $g$ is continuous it must change sign in the interval. In order to have the desired inequality the function $h$ needs "to be large" in the region where $g$ is positive and small (or negative) in the region where $g$ is negative. There is no magic

Comment: If you are asking which functions $h$ will satisfy that $hg$ will have positive integral, the answer is any function $h$ such that the positive values $hg$ have larger area than the negative values of $hg;$ one such $h$ can be $\min(g, 0).$ Then $hg \geq 0$ and positive on a positive measure set so $hg$ has positive integral; there are infinitely many choices for $h$ by the way.

Comment: There is no assumption you can make about $h$ such that $\int_0^T hg >0$ *for all* $g$ with $\int_0^T g = 0$. If you were to give some continuous function $h \ne 0$, I can always define a $g$ that would make the integral negative. Thus any condition on $h$ that will meet your request *must* involve $g$. Once you allow for that, then many sufficient conditions exist, for instance that $\text{sign}(h) = \text{sign}(g)$. For necessary conditions, the best you can say is what Icv and William M. have already said.